# VB.Net MySql command parameter MD5

Tags: mysql, vb.net, parameterized

Is it possible to execute a command like this?

```
select * from tbl where col1=somefunction(@param1)
```

or will the parameter throw off the function?  I have been unsuccessful in getting the command to work so far.

Please let me know if this needs any further explanation and thank you in advance!

Comment: You should use a secure hash.

Comment: No error, the query just returns no results when it definitely should return one.  Other parameterized queries work, just not with md5.

Answer (score 1):

IN VBNet:

```
Shared Sub Main()
    con = New MySqlConnection("Your ConnectionString") 

    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("select * from tbl where col1 = somefunction(@param1)", con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1","value HEre")

    Try
        con.Open()
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", reader.GetString(0))
        End While
        reader.Close()
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```